# Finding nth largest number (many times) when the array size is increasing

Tags: java, algorithm

We can easily find the nth largest using the ***Median of Medians Algorithm*** in *O(n)* time complexity.
If we have to find multiple times the nth largest numbers in the same array the best would be to sort *O(NlogN)*  and then find the number in *O(1)* time complexity.
 But what will be the efficient algorithm when the array size is increasing and
we have to find the nth largest number say array.length/3 th largest or  array.length/2 th  largest.
**Example**

```
Array- 1,3,2,4,5 n=2 Answer-4   
New Array 1,3,2,4,5,7  n=2 answer-5  
New Array 1,3,2,4,5,7,3 n=2 answer-5
```

**Note**
n depends upon length of the array.
Please do help me.

Comment: If this is homework please add the homework tag.

Comment: Algorithms are rarely efficient (or inefficient) in isolation, more generally they are (in-)efficient wrt a particular data structure.  For example, if you keep all your numbers in an array which is sorted at all times, inserting new elements in their correct location and shuffling the others around, you'll get very quick access to the n-th largest at all times, relatively slow updating.  Can you refine your requirements ?

Comment: Is it necessary. I have already done my homework . I know why you are saying  this. But you can easily understand that how much effort i have put in  to arrive at this. ( We can easily find the nth largest using the Median of Medians Algorithm in O(n) time complexity).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark   Finding the nth largest number(various times) where n depends upon the total number Of elements. Total number of elements are not fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm convinced that you have to keep track of the entire array at all times.  Suppose that we receive 100, 99, 98, ..., 1, 0, -1, ...  Then the nth-largest number will follow the same sequence, albeit slowed down: 100, 100, 99, 99, 98, 98...

Essentially, we can't forget any numbers from the input, because in this scenario each number will eventually be chosen as the nth largest.

That said, there's an O(log N) algorithm (for N, the number of elements overall) to "update" the nth largest element each time we read in a new element, which seems probably optimal.  More or less, just keep a min priority queue of the n largest elements, and a max priority queue of the N-n smaller elements.  Whenever n increases (array.length / 3 increases, for example), pull something out of the smaller-elements queue into the larger-elements queue; every time we read a new element, put it into the appropriate queue, possibly bumping an element out of the "larger-elements" queue into the "smaller-elements" queue.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. It depends on how many of the values are unique and how often you start with a new array, search and insert.

For many of n being unique, rarely starting with a new array with frequent insertion/searching, my first hunch would be:

- Create a max-heap `tip` and a max-heap `bulk`, let n be the rank you want (nth value)
- Insert:  push new node into `tip`; if `tip.size() >= (n-1)`, pop `tip.top()` and push into `bulk`
- Search:  return `bulk.top()`

That should give you `O(N log(N))` for startup, `O(log(N))` for insertion (much faster than sorting) and `O(1)` for searching.

If the number of unique values is much smaller than N, I would probably use counting sort and then sort the bins by value.

**EDIT**: Looking at Louis Wasserman's answer in some more detail, it seems to overlap almost completely with my first algorithm. However, would still like to suggest that instead of pulling *"something out of the smaller-elements queue"*, you can make the search O(1) by picking the max element as the one to push into the min-heap.

Comment: The "search" is O(1) in my algorithm -- it's just the min element of the larger-elements queue -- but any push or pop into a priority queue is going to be O(log n).