# What is the fastest way to find Nth biggest number of an INT array?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want a faster function to find the Nth biggest number of an Int array in C#. This function takes N and Array and returns **index** of that number.

Here is what i have already. It simply sorts the array and then returns the index of that number. **It works perfectly** but I'm not sure if this is the fastest way. it seems logical to be an algorithm without complete sorting.

```
static int myFunction(int[] array, int N){
    int[] indexes = new int[array.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
        indexes[i] = i;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] < array[j])
            {
                int m = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i];
                array[i] = m;

                m = indexes[j];
                indexes[j] = indexes[i];
                indexes[i] = m;
            }
        }
    }
    return indexes[N];
}
```

some results :

```
myFunction(new int[] { 1, 3, 2, 0, 10 }, 0); //returns 4 (index of 10)
myFunction(new int[] { 1, 3, 2, 0, 10 }, 1); //returns 1 (index of 3)
myFunction(new int[] { 1, 3, 2, 0, 10 }, 2); //returns 2 (index of 2)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393019/finding-nth-largest-number-many-times-when-the-array-size-is-increasing?rq=1

Comment: Why are you writing your own sorting algorithm? It's ok if you want to understand it, but bubble sort isn't the fastest out there. If you don't want the hassle of writing your own implementation of quicksort, there's also `Array.Sort`.

Comment: your sort is n^2, so clearly no, it is not the fastest.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ, Sorry for off topic question, but how did you styled your name this way? How can I style mine the same way?

Comment: @TaReQMahMooD Honestly, I too had to search a lot (believe me) for that thing. I discovered it is known as Small Caps. -> [Tᴀʀᴇǫ Mᴀʜᴍᴏᴏᴅ](http://fsymbols.com/smallcaps/#s=Tareq%20Mahmood)

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ, Thanks for the help and info. (I need to wait for another month to update my name, already updated once this month).

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ, Just wanted to give you the final thanks. I have just updated my name in profile.  :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Randomized quickselect algorithm works in average case complexity O(n). Practically it's very rare to be O(n^2). It uses quicksort's partition function

Comment: [QuickSelect on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect), and [an implementation in C# here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quickselect_algorithm)

Comment: but it has Worst case performance of n^2, although I don't quite understand if k is considered as a constant, or as n.

Answer (score 27):

If your array has a size of a zillion numbers and you need the fifth largest number then you are sorting a lot of numbers that you won't need.

Wouldn't it be faster to keep an ascending sorted sequence of length n (linked list?), and for every element check if it is larger than the first one (which is the smallest in the ascending order

- If smaller: skip to the next element in your large array
- If larger: remove the smallest one from your sorted array which is the first element and insert the larger element in the proper place, keep the array sorted.

After having scanned your complete array, the first element in your sorted sequence is the one you are looking for.

Most comparisons are only with the first element of your sorted array. You'll have to change the array N-times, one time for the N largest numbers. A change of the array is to remove the first element (the smallest) and find the place where to insert the new element to keep the array sorted

> Correction: my statement that the array has to be changed N-time is incorrect. This can be seen most easily when offering an array sorted in ascending order: every compared number will be larger than the smallest in the N-size array, and thus cause a replace

Comment: I would point that a sorted linked-list is overkill. A min-heap of size N (heap head is smaller than all other elements) is sufficient to select the N biggest elements, and its head is the N-th biggest which exactly answers the question. Even if you want the N biggest elements sorted at the end, it's better to proceed with the min-heap during their selection as the heap will require less maintenance than a sorted list in general.

Comment: This is also the first algorithm I though of, with running time O(n * N) — for every element in the array you'll have to compare with N elements to see if it should be on your shortlist. In case of a small N (or bad luck for quickselect) it might be better to use this, but for larger N I guess that quickselect would be faster.

Comment: @MatthieuM. 's suggestion of using a min-heap drives it down to O(n log(N)).

Comment: Daan said: "you'll have to compare with N elements to see if it should be on your shortlist". Why? If the array is sorted I only have to compare with the first element, don't I?

Answer (score 13):

This would be the implementation of @HaraldDutch's answer.

```
int get(int[] array, int n)
{
    var comparer = Comparer<int>.Create((x, y) => array[x].CompareTo(array[y]));    //compare the array entries, not the indices
    var highestIndices = new SortedSet<int>(comparer);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        var entry = array[i];
        if (highestIndices.Count < n) highestIndices.Add(i);
        else if (array[highestIndices.Min] < entry)
        {
            highestIndices.Remove(highestIndices.Min);
            highestIndices.Add(i);
        }
    }

    return highestIndices.Min;
}
```

You'd have to pass in 1 instead of 0 though.

Comment: You could possibly do this in one pass by tracking the indexes.

Comment: The post-process approach is also problematic in the case of non-unique entries making the shortlist. Keeping the indices is minimal in overhead.

Comment: This does not work in cases where our array contains repeat values.

Comment: @user2697817 Thanks for the hint. Sorry it took me so long to update the answer.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq yeah, I chose to ignore the fact that repeated values are possible, because I dont know how it should behave. Should it treat repeated values as one, or still count them as multiple ones?

Comment: @Keith you are right, tracking the indices actually made the code *shorter*

Answer (score 9):

you need to use Selection algorithm
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

here nice slides: https://c3p0demo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/scalaDemo/script/Order_statistics.ppt
generally algorithm:

```
Select(A,n,i):
    Divide input into ⌈n/5⌉ groups of size 5.

    /* Partition on median-of-medians */
    medians = array of each group’s median.
    pivot = Select(medians, ⌈n/5⌉, ⌈n/10⌉)
    Left Array L and Right Array G = partition(A, pivot)

    /* Find ith element in L, pivot, or G */
    k = |L| + 1
    If i = k, return pivot
    If i < k, return Select(L, k-1, i)
    If i > k, return Select(G, n-k, i-k)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could create a heap of size N which has the largest number as its first element (as opposed to the smallest one usually given).  Then you walk through your integer array, and whenever you have an element smaller than the largest member of the heap, you insert it into the heap.  If that makes the heap exceed a size of N, you remove the largest member in it.

That should be one of the cheapest ways to do this.  Specific "nth largest of m" algorithms may beat it, but probably not asymptotically.

Answer (score 5):

Your sorting algorithm is by far not the fastest. You should google for "Quicksort" for a much, much faster algorithm.

And after you have implemented Quicksort, you would then think about whether you really needed to sort the complete array. Say you want to find the 20 largest out of 10,000 numbers, why would you sort the remaining 9,980 numbers? You can easily modify Quicksort so that it will find the N largest numbers but mostly ignore the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help someone. finding the nth largest number in an int array.

```
            int[] arr = new int[] { 3, 2, 1, 5 };
            Array.Sort(arr);
            int elemCount = 0;
            int? thirdLargestNumber = null;
            foreach (var elem in arr)
            {
                var temp = arr.Skip(elemCount).ToArray();
                if (temp.Length == 3) //replace `3` with variable.
                { 
                    thirdLargestNumber = temp[0];
                    break;
                }
                elemCount++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Third largest number = {thirdLargestNumber}");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it with Linq in C#. The `OrderBy()` and `OrderByDescending()` sorting in Linq uses **Quick Sort with O(N*logN) of average time complexity.**.

```
private static List<int> GetNthLargestNumber(List<int> integerList, int nThPosition)
{       
    // Write your logic here.
    var largestNumbers = integerList
        .Select((v,i) => new { Index = i, Value = v })
        .GroupBy(s=>s.Value)
        .OrderByDescending(s=>s.Key) // uses Quick sort with O(N*logN) average time complexity.
        .Skip(nThPosition - 1)
        .First()
        .ToList();
    
    foreach(var n in largestNumbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{n.Index}->{n.Value}" );
    }
    
    var largestNumberIndexes = largestNumbers.Select(s=> s.Index).ToList();
    
    return largestNumberIndexes;
}
```

I have whole working program at https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rz8r6A